# Pausing Recursive Function Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, recursion, settimeout

I have a function of which I'm supposed to pause on `mouseenter` and pause on `mouseleave` but the problem is that the function is recursive. You pass in a parent and index and it will recursively loop through each inner div displaying and hiding. The function looks like this:

```
var delay = 1000;
function cycle(variable, j){
    var jmax = jQuery(variable + " div").length;
    jQuery(variable + " div:eq(" + j + ")")
        .css('display', 'block')
        .animate({opacity: 1}, 600)
        .animate({opacity: 1}, delay)
        .animate({opacity: 0}, 800, function(){
            if(j+1 === jmax){ 
                j=0;
            }else{ 
                j++;
            }
            jQuery(this).css('display', 'none').animate({opacity: 0}, 10);

            cycle(variable, j);
        });
}
```

I've tried setting a timeout and clearing it but it doesn't seem to do anything (it seems to ignore the timeout entirely), I've tried using stop() and calling the function again on mouseout but that seemed to repeat the function call (I was seeing duplicates) and it stopped mid animation which didn't work. I tried adding in a default variable at one point (`var pause = false || true;`) but I also couldn't get it to work as expected (though I feel the solution relies on that variable). I'm open to all suggestions but there are some rules of engagement:

**Rules:** There can't be any major changes in how this function works as many things rely on it, it's something I do not have control over. Assume the function call looks like this `jQuery('#divList', 0)` and holds a bunch of `div` elements as children.

The timeout function is the last solution I tried which looks like:

```
jQuery('#divList').on('mouseenter', function(){
    setTimeout(cycle, 100000);
})
.on('mouseleave', function(){
    window.clearTimeout();
});
```

Comment: When using `stop`, you need to pass `true` as an argument to prevent callbacks from being called.

Comment: `window.clearTimeout` requires a timeout ID which is returned from the `setTimeout` function.

Comment: That solution with a `pause` variable should work as well. Can you post the whole code of that try?

Comment: Technical issue here: This isn't a recursive call since only one instance of the `cycle` function exists at a time.  This uses events to re-invoke itself -- something very different from a technical point of view.  Were this *actually* recursive, you wouldn't be able to pause it.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher Isn't any function that calls itself recursive? So wouldn't this be a [recursive loop](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Recursive+loop)?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Yes, any function that calls itself is cursive, but this function is *not* called by itself -- it is called by an *event handler*, which is different.  In a recursive function, you have the ability to return a value to the calling function -- they all exist stacked up and waiting.  When recalling via a event handler, there is only one instance of the function in existence at a time.  (In this case, the event is being handled by the jQuery animate, which uses the Javascript `setTimeout` to handle the animation, then when the animation is done is calls the callback function.)

Comment: Do you want your opacity animation to stop in the middle when paused and resume there?

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher I could move the function outside the animation event handler and it would function be the same. Recursion is [any function that calls itself](http://www.techterms.com/definition/recursivefunction) within itself. You do not need multiple instances of the same function to make it recursive even though it is the most common form of recursion. Thus why this is a recursive loop, which could be turned into normal `for` loop really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this? I simplified the animation just to make the example simpler, but you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

First, we have a function that's responsible for animating a set of elements. Every function call returns a new function that allows to toggle the animation (transition between pause and resume).

```
function startCycleAnimation(els) {

    var index = 0,
        $els = $(els),
        $animatedEl;

    animate($nextEl());

    return pauseCycleAnimation;

    function animate($el, startOpacity) {
        $el.css('opacity', startOpacity || 1)
           .animate({ opacity: 0 }, 800, function () {
                animate($nextEl());
            });
    }

    function $nextEl() {
        index = index % $els.length;
        return $animatedEl = $els.slice(index++, index);
    }

    function pauseCycleAnimation() {
        $animatedEl.stop(true);

        return resumeCycleAnimation;
    }

    function resumeCycleAnimation() {
         animate($animatedEl, $animatedEl.css('opacity'));

         return pauseCycleAnimation;
    }
}
```

Then we can kick-start everything with something like:

```
$(function () {
    var $animationContainer = $('#animation-container'),
        toggleAnimation = startCycleAnimation($animationContainer.children('div'));

    $animationContainer.mouseenter(pauseOrResume).mouseleave(pauseOrResume);

    function pauseOrResume() {
        toggleAnimation = toggleAnimation();
    }
});
```

Example HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="animation-container">
        <div>Div 1</div>
        <div>Div 2</div>
        <div>Div 3</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you want something more generic, it seems [there's a plugin](http://tobia.github.io/Pause/) that overrides `animate` and allows to pause/resume animations in a generic way.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put a flag that each `cycle` checks before it determines if it is going to run. Then you can just change that flag when the mouse events are triggered. If you need to pick up where you left off when you unpause, consider saving the last value of `j`

```
function cycle(variable, j){
    if (window.paused) {
        window.last_j = j;
        return;
    }
    ...
```

Then when you want to pause, just set `window.paused = true` . To resume, change it back to false and call `cycle` again:

```
cycle(variable, last_j);
```

Comment: There's no reason to make this a global `window` property, especially since `cycle` can be invoked multiple times with different arguments.

Comment: I tried this but it never paused (I got all my expected console messages though) then multiple divs started appearing and cycling like there were multiple instances of the function: [Paste Bin Code](http://pastebin.com/1tsAV6j8)